# Translating fullcalendar using I18n and coffee script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, coffeescript, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar in my Ruby-On_Rails app. I want to internationalize it. In my coffee script I have:

```
monthNames: ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre'] if $('#calendar').data('url') == 'es'
```

This works perfectly for English and Spanish. But if I add support for a third language, like this:

```
monthNames: ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre'] if $('#calendar').data('url') == 'es'

monthNames:['janvier','février','mars','avril','mai','juin','juillet','août','septembre','octobre','novembre','décembre'] if $('#calendar').data('url') == 'fr'
```

Then it will work for English and French but not for Spanish( it will default to English). I am new to coffee script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how CoffeeScript handles a postfix `if` within the context of a property initialization. A short example should help; given this:

```
o =
  a: 6  if(x)
  a: 11 if(y)
```

you get [this JavaScript](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3ao%20=%0A%20%20a%3a%206%20%20if%28x%29%0A%20%20a%3a%2011%20if%28y%29):

```
var o;
o = {
  a: x ? 6 : void 0,
  a: y ? 11 : void 0
};
```

But you can't have duplicate keys in an object so you'll end up with the last one. The result is that you're really just saying:

```
o =
  a: 11 if(y)
```

in a complicated way. In your case, you'll be using the value from the French conditional no matter what (since it is the last one) so the month names end up being `undefined`.

You should be able to fix your problem by moving your month names to a separate object indexed by language:

```
monthsInLang =
  es: ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre']
  fr: ['janvier','février','mars','avril','mai','juin','juillet','août','septembre','octobre','novembre','décembre']
  # Any others you want...
```

and then set your `monthNames` like this:

```
monthNames: monthsInLang[$('#calendar').data('url')]
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks for your help, this really saved me a lot of time as I was struggling with coffee script.

Comment: You're welcome. Using the *TRY COFFEESCRIPT* tool at http://coffeescript.org is very helpful when you're starting out.